# Accessing SPI driver with ADB

Tags: android, adb, device-driver, spi

I have a SPI channel ennabled on my Android Eval board. With ADB, I get to

```
# adb shell cat /sys/bus/spi/devices/spi0.0/uevent
DRIVER=spidev
OF_NAME=device
OF_FULLNAME=/soc/spi@07575000/device@0
OF_COMPATIBLE_0=spidev
OF_COMPATIBLE_N=1
MODALIAS=spi:spidev
```

I searched the web but did not found how to write to this SPI channel in debug (A.K.A adb) without an external driver/application. I'd like to send dummy data on this SPI to know if my pins are correctly configured.

My question is: Which command would get me to send data on SPI with ADB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the driver running, you can write raw bytes to spi driver `file` directly using `adb shell echo` command or `dd`.
For example in my device the power button device file is  `\dev\input\event0`, The raw data to be send to hardware to turn off display(single press) is `\012`-

> adb shell echo echo -e "\012" > /dev/input/event0

Also if you have the data to be written as binary file you can do `dd`

> adb shell dd if=./record1 of=/dev/input/event0

you need to know your hardawre in `\dev\` and use above commands.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed. I wrote
```adb shell
echo -ne "\xFFF" > /dev/spidev0.0
```